# Installing Windows XP from USB, Grub Rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, windows-xp

On my netbook (HP mini 110) there was a `LUBUNTU` (do not remember which one) operating system. I Tried to install Windows XP.

The hard disk format was `EXT4`. To change the hard disk format from `ext4` to `ntfs` I did this.

1) Downloaded and extracted .iso file into USB using `rufus`
,

2) Ran the `Lubuntu` ISO from usb,

3) Ran the `GParted` program and changed the main hard disk to `ntfs` type.

I then burned the `Windows XP` ISO to usb again, Changed boot priority (made usb first readable drive)

The problem is that when I turn on the computer, after a few seconds, this error occurred:

> error: unknown filesystem.
>
> Entering rescue mode...
>
> grub rescue>

Nothing about `WINDOWS` is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced the same error after I deleted the partition with Ubuntu while dual booting my PC. This error happens because the `grub` cannot find the right Ubuntu partition when you load the computer. This happens when you format the partition wrong.

**To fix this try the following:**

1. Write the Ubuntu 16.04 ISO to a file.
2. Boot it up into the installation menu.
3. Choose the 'Try Ubuntu' button. (NOT THE INSTALL BUTTON)
4. Open the terminal.
5. Type in `sudo apt-get purge grub* && sudo apt-get autoremove`
6. Reboot the system to then install your OS (Windows XP).

***I hope this works :D***

Comment: Is it ok, if I will try it with lubuntu .iso file?

Comment: This appearing when trying to run from USB: end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Comment: I have tried with ubuntu, not working

Comment: That error message is the one that I had received, and this seemed to clear it, but I do not quite understand how you are trying to install Windows and what the current state of your computer is (Does it currently have an OS installed), Sorry :D.